# arguments in callback functions

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, callback

```
function listenforremoval(){
   let db=database.length;
   for(var i=0;i<db;i++){
  document.getElementById(`btn-${i}`).addEventListener("click",deletedata.bind(null,i));
    }
}



function deletedata(index){
    let db=database.length;
    console.log(database);
    console.log(index);
    for(var i=0;i<db;i++){
        if(database[i][0]===index){
            database.splice(i,1);
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log(database);
    renderpage(); 
}
```

in the above code i am trying to call deletedata(index) when the event click happens.
but it only runs for single time . next time when i click the element ,no action takes place.

What might be the issue?

Comment: Why are you adding multiple listeners to the same button?

Comment: What does `renderpage()` do? If it rewrites the HTML that includes the button, the event listener is lost because you're creating all new DOM elements.

Comment: actually the elements are different i made a mistake in code .it should be id=`btn-${i}`

Comment: yes it renders the HTML...how can i keep the event listener alive ..or how can i create a new one

Comment: Run the JavaScript code again after rendering the page.

Comment: ya it works ...thankyou